# How to change the thesis template's reference format

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I am using the following link's template for completing my thesis. The current version uses [1], [2] as the reference format. But I want to use the (Last Name 2019) or Last name (2019) as my reference format.

I am trying to achieve above format by:

1- adding `\\usepackage{natbib}` in thesis.tex file;

2- comment `\RequirePackage[backend=biber,sorting=none,bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}` in the rutgersthesis.cls file and add "\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibliography{references.bib}" in the thesis.tex file, which is I need.

Can anyone help for this? Many thanks! The original codes are from the following link:

https://github.com/tangbao/RU-Thesis-Dissertation-Latex-Template

```
\documentclass[12pt]{rutgersthesis}

% preamble

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Your information here
% !IMPORTANT!
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\thesisType}{Dissertation } % Dissertation for PhD and Thesis for Master
\newcommand{\thesisTitle}{Title} % your thesis/dissertation title, e.g., How to Write A Thesis
\newcommand{\yourName}{Name} % your name, e.g., Tim Cook
\newcommand{\yourDegree}{Doctor of Philosophy} % your degree to be obtained, e.g., Master of Science, Doctor of Philosophy
\newcommand{\yourProgram}{Graduate Program} %insert your graduate program’s official name
\newcommand{\yourDirectorTitle}{Prof.} % the title of your thesis director
\newcommand{\yourDirector}{Dissertation/Thesis Director} % your thesis director name here, his/her title not included
\newcommand{\yourCommitteeNumber}{4} % IMPORTANT! the number of the committee members for your defense
\newcommand{\yourMonth}{Month} % your graduation month, not your defense month
\newcommand{\yourYear}{Year} % your graduation year


\bibliography{references}

% document body
\begin{document}
% \doublespacing  %set line spacing

\input{copyright}

\makeTitlePage{Month}{Year}

\begin{frontmatter}
    \input{abstract}
    \input{acknowledgments}
    \makeTOC
    \makeListOfTables
    \makeListOfFigures
    \input{abbrevs}
\end{frontmatter}

\begin{thesisbody}
    \input{chapters/chapter1}
    \input{chapters/chapter2}
    % \input{chapters/chapter3}
    % \input{chapters/chapter4}
    % \input{chapters/chapter5.tex}
    % \input{chapters/appendix.tex}
    \input{publications.tex}
    \makeBibliography
\end{thesisbody}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It's not clear to me how well-advised your proposed changes are. You're using this particular document class because you're about to submit a (master's? Ph.D.?) thesis to Rutgers, right? If so, it's presumably highly inadvisable to switch the citation style and they way the bibliography items are formatted so radically, right? By the way, if you're not preparing to submit a thesis to Rutgers, why would you employ this particular document class to begin with? Please clarify.

Comment: There are other ruthesis classes on github (and see the university site). Have you got the right class file? There seem to be different files and guidelines for computing science, arts, maths, the graduate school, and so on. The author-year one would be for the social sciences, I would expect. There may be one for your needs. It generally should not be necessary to reinvent the wheel.